# laravel phpunit test global method

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm writing tests for a project in `laravel` and it's working well. However, is is there an optimization for my code here? There is repetition that seems removable, but nothing worked when I tried.

```
public function testApplIndex()
{
    $this->get('api/protected/app/index?X-Auth-Token='.Config::get('constants.X_AUTH_TOKEN'));

    // check if response 200 OK
    $this->assertResponseOk();

    // Get the response
    $jsonResponse = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();

    //display response
    if (Config::get('constants.DISPLAY') == true) {
        echo $jsonResponse;
    }

}

public function testCompanyApp()
{
    $this->get('api/protected/app/company_apps?X-Auth-Token='.Config::get('constants.X_AUTH_TOKEN').'&co_id='.Config::get('constants.CO_ID'));

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    // Get the response
    $jsonResponse = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();

    //display response
    if (Config::get('constants.DISPLAY') == true) {
        echo $jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is that "nothing" that you tried? :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can extract the same code please do see example:

```
public function testApplIndex()
{
    $this->someName('api/protected/app/index?X-Auth-Token='.Config::get('constants.X_AUTH_TOKEN'));

}

public function testCompanyApp()
{
    $this->someName('api/protected/app/company_apps?X-Auth-Token='.Config::get('constants.X_AUTH_TOKEN').'&co_id='.Config::get('constants.CO_ID'));

}

private function someName($p)
{
    $this->get($p);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    // Get the response
    $jsonResponse = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();

    //display response
    if (Config::get('constants.DISPLAY') == true) {
        echo $jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying here is a series of endpoints that you want to return a specific type of result. A single function can handle that:

```
public function test_endpoint($endpoint)
{
    $this->get($endpoint);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    // Get the response
    $jsonResponse = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();

    //display response
    if (Config::get('constants.DISPLAY') == true) {
        echo $jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is test your series of endpoints:

```
public function testAllOkEndpoints(){
    $endpoints = array('api/protected/app/index?X-Auth-Token='.Config::get('constants.X_AUTH_TOKEN',
                       'api/protected/app/company_apps?X-Auth-Token='.Config::get('constants.X_AUTH_TOKEN').'&co_id='.Config::get('constants.CO_ID'));
    foreach ($endpoints as $endpoint) {
        $hits->test_endpoint($endpoint);
    } 
}
```

Using this method, as you add endpoints you need to simply add them to the array of endpoints you are testing where you expect the response to be `200 OK`.